# Silverlight 4 Controls

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have a problem with Silverlight 4. The problem is that i am developing on a 24" monitor screen. When i get home from work i continue to develop on my laptop which only has 19" monitor screen.

And what really irretates me is that the controls is not where i want them to be.

The controls are added upon each other. I am using simple controls like Buttons, textboxes etc.

I do also have the controls within a Grid.Row and a Grid.Column. I have tried with StackPanels also inside the grid and in the Columns etc. Also tried to have Stackpanel and a Grid inside, and i also tried with Canvas.

On Experts-Exchange a member wrote that this is a common problem in Silverlight - which i definitely do not believe.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. I develop on an HD 24" monitor at work and take the laptop home to use the 15" screen. I never have this issue. But when I first started developing in SL I used grids for everything and some times experienced this. I like to use stackpanels now to position things more relatively when I can. Whith the grid are you using * with your measures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing for multiple resolutions, use the design size handles to keep re-sizing your interface.

If the interface just cannot go below a certain size, set that as the MinHeight/MinWidth and place it all in a scrollviewer. That way scrollbars will simply kick in if the screen gets too small to be usable for your design.

Silverlight grids are a lot like HTML tables in that you need to flex them about a lot to ensure you have correctly linked to the right edges/positions. Silverlight has more options  (thanks to stretch etc) and it just takes practice to learn how to nest the boxing model to do what you want.

Comment: Hi HiTech Magic. I have found out that using the Vertical, HorizonticalAlligenment property and setting it to Strech, gives a much more re-sizing controls. It didn't give a 100 Procent resize design but. Thanks all for the help provided i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that this is a common problem with Silverlight.  It isn't that it isn't possible to get it right, but sometimes getting all of the controls to line up properly using different resolutions can be a challenge.  Often a challenge that developers just don't take the time to solve.

For me it just comes down to trial and error with regards to setting row and column width/heights to Auto, *, and fixed and then combining this with StackPanels and ScrollViewers.  I haven't used it, but I believe one of the Developer Toolkits had a StackGrid, or something like that.  It combined the functionality of stackpanels and grids into a single control.  I've heard others claim that using that control made things easier.

Pay attention to Vertical/Horizontal Alignment and Margins to help position the controls too.

Comment: @Jeff - Any info on StackGrid would be usefull if you can pass it on. The Googles have nothing...

Comment: @Jeff Thank you very much. Could you please post a link to the StackGrid? I need to make a smooth design and i using differnt kind of Charts(silverlight Tool Kit) and it is much easiser to make good design with Expression Blend and Silverlight rather than using ASP.NET.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find the control I was talking about.  However, if you go here: http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html you can find a DockPanel which may help you with your layout needs.  I'll look some more for the control I was thinking of.

Comment: I found the control I was thinking of, but it I guess I misremembered what it did.  While I think it is a good control, I don't think it will actually help your problem.  (SuperStackPanel)

Comment: Robert: I don't use "*" in my grid measures. I try look at the control.

Comment: Yes, check out star. If you have anything that should be proportional, then start is typically used.  It is rare that I use a grid without * being used somewhere.

Comment: Isn't there any code I can write to get the screensize and set then make some calculations pr. Grid row and column to fit.? I know it sounds like a very stupid situation, but I don't really want to make the design from scratch again.